# Finding Length of List in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm running Prolog and trying to write a small function returning the length of a list:

```
len([],0).
len([XS], Y) :-
    len([X|XS], M),
    Y is M+1.
```

My logic is that the recursive call should include the tail of the list (XS) and increase 1 to the previous length (Y is M+1.)

This always returns false.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a general methodology for debugging and testing Prolog predicates:

### Start with the most general query!

Think of it: In Prolog you do not need to make up some test data. You don't even need to understand a predicate at all: Just hand in free variables! That is always a professional move!

So in your case, that's

```
?- len(L,N).
   L = [], N = 0
;  loops.
```

Your definition is not that bad as you claim: At least, it is true for the empty list.

Now, maybe look at the compiler warnings you probably received:

```
Warning: user://1:11:
        Singleton variables: [X]
```

Next read the recursive rule **in the direction of the arrow `:-`** that is, right-to-left:

Provided `len([X|Xs], M)` is true and `Y is M+1` is true, provided all that is true, we can conclude that

`len([XS], Y)` is true as well. So you are always concluding something about a list of length 1 (`[Xs]`).

You need to reformulate this to `len([X|Xs], M) :- len(Xs,  N), Y is M+1`.

And here is another strategy:

### Generalize your program

By removing goals, we can generalize a program<sup>1</sup>. Here is my favorite way to do it. By adding a predicate `(*)/1` like so:

```
:- op(950,fy, *).

*_.
```

Now, let's remove all goals from your program:

```
len([],0).
len([XS], Y) :-
    * len([X|XS], M),
    * Y is M+1.
```

What we have now is a generalization. Once again, we will look at the answers of the most general query:

```
?- len(L, N).
   L = [], N = 0
;  L = [_].
```

What? `len/2` is only true for lists of length 0 and 1.  That means, even `len([1,2], N)` fails! So now we know for sure: something in the visible remaining part of the program has to be fixed. In fact, `[XS]` just describes lists of length 1. So this has to be removed...

---

Fine print:

<sub>1 Certain restrictions apply. Essentially, your program has to be a pure, monotonic program.</sub>

Comment: I want to generalize some subterms in rule heads and bodies, say, `foo(1,2,X) :- ... .` to `foo(_,_,X) :- ... .` How can I indicate *that* visually?  Ideally, I would use `(*)/1` "inside" the term... Could I use term_expansion to do that? I would rather not translate to extra unify goals.

Comment: @repeat: First translate these "hard coded" terms to `foo(A1,A2,X) :- A1 = 1, A2 = 2, ...`

Comment: @repeat: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) way is to write `foo(_/*1*/,_/*2*/,X) :- ...` as you can imagine, I am moderately happy with this.