# SWI-Prolog : "false" where?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

Normally when the goal fail I get back "false" i.e. the goal was not satisfied.
Is there a way to make SWI-Prolog to print predicate, line and/or sequence number of the sub-goal where it failed.
I don't want to trace the whole program just want some feedback sort of like in other programming languages.
I know it is not error to return `false`, but when debugging it will be nice to have this feedback to pinpoint problems. If it is possible of course.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to consider using the "failure-slice" technique described many times by @false: it has [its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

Also, check out [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788208/gprolog-getting-a-stacktrace-after-an-exception/30791637#30791637). You can use the code shown there to make your own "debugger" that lets you do (among other things) exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
...p1, p2, (p3;backtrace(10)), p4,...
```

could also be useful to start tracing after p3 is failing:

```
...p1, p2, (p3;backtrace(10),trace), p4,...
```