# What is the explanation of this code (Prolog)?

Tags: prolog, backtracking, trace

I am trying to learn Prolog. I have a problem and the solution for that in Prolog. Though I am unable to understand the code completely.

The call of the code goes like this-

```
conc(Before,[c|After],[a,b,c,d]) .
```

This code will return

```
 Before = [a,b]
    After = [d]
```

I have the solution -

```
conc([],L,L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :- conc(L1,L2,L3) .
```

I am not able to understand the flow of the program completely. Let me start with a dry run. I added some write command in order understand the code flow. The code now looks like this -

```
conc([],L,L):-  write("Line1: "), write(L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :-
     write("Line-2: "), write(L1), write(" "), 
     write(L2), write(" "), write(L3), conc(L1,L2,L3) .
```

Initial call is -

```
 conc(Before,[c|After],[a,b,c,d]) .
```

At this moment, the call goes to line 2 (because, Before is unknown term which is not empty)which is :

```
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :-
    write("Line-2: "), write(L1), write(" "),
    write(L2), write(" "), write(L3), conc(L1,L2,L3) .
```

At this point, X=[a], l1= unknown, L2=[c|After] and L3=[b,c,d]. This prints -

**Line2: _G481 [c|_G368] [b,c,d]**

This will again call the recursion(code line 2) with the following value:

```
cons(L1, [c|After], [b,c,d]). (L1 is unknown still now)
```

And, prints -

**Line2: _G494 [c|_G368] [c,d]**

Now the next call will be :

```
cons(L1, [c|After], [c,d]).
```

But , I can see while printing the customized comments in the code, that, at this point the code control goes to #line 1 which I am not able to understand. Because, now,

```
L1= unknown(just as all the previous calls).
L(parameter 2)= [c|After]
L(parameter 3) = [c,d].
```

But, the control goes to the #line 1, and it prints :

```
Line1: [c,d]
```

I thought prolog executes the code from left to right. So, as per my understanding, while executing the value of L should be [c,d].

***My question is:***

**1. After the second call, L1 is undefined as all the calls as before. And, second and third parameters , both are L. So, why, after second call the control goes to the #line1.?**

**2. Is my understanding correct in this matter ? "I thought prolog executes the code from left to right. So, as per my understanding, while executing the value of L should be [c,d]."**

Thanks in advance...
Please help me out!!

Comment: Please try this to make your life easier: `?- format("~w ~w ~w\n", [a,b,c]).`

Comment: IMO you are not looking for explanations, but for procedural program traces.

Comment: Before trying to understand this, learn Prolog [tag:dcg] formalism.

Comment: There is a [simpler way to annotate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) your programs.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect to understand everything that is happening here if you look at it procedurally, because there is too much going on at the same time. This is especially true if you are just beginning to learn the language.

A good approach for learning Prolog is to think *declaratively*, and ask: *What* are the conditions that make this *hold*?

In addition, you are currently writing atoms when you actually mean to write variables. Please correct your post to say for example:

```
cons(L1, [c|After], [c,d])
```

Note that `After` is a variable, and `after` is an *atom*.

Now, leaving everything else aside, just consider this single goal in isolation. Try it with:

`?- cons(L1, [c|After], [c,d]).`

In complete accordance with our expectation, we get the solution:

```
L1 = [],
After = [d]
```

Thus, it suffices to understand that this goal can be derived in isolation. Also notice the difference between `X = [a]` and `X = a`, which you are currently intermingling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But, actually I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. My question was -     1. After the second call, L1 is undefined as all the calls as before. And, second and third parameters , both are L. So, why, after second call the control goes to the #line1.?

Comment: As I said: Try to understand, from the program you give, why and under what conditions the isolated goal `cons(L1, [c|After], [c,d])` is true. From this, you obtain the answer to your question. Please keep in mind that there are several control flows at work in Prolog, such as one (AND) for the goals within a rule body, and another (OR) for proving a single goal. You are currently speaking about the control flow as if there is only one. In general, your terminology needs to improve to discuss this in more detail. For example, a Prolog term can never be "undefined". It is always a Prolog term.