# Program doesnt work. Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some problem whith this code. The func3 was never invoked :

```
technology(board, saw, table).
technology(wood, sanded, board).
technology(water, grow, tree).

material(table, board, 20).
material(table, tree, 5).
material(wood, water, 100).

equipment(table,saw, cut, 10).
equipment(board, plane, polish, 7).
equipment(tree, watering, growing, 100).

specialization(saw, wood).
specialization(plane, wood).
specialization(watering, forestry).

plan_vypusku(table,10).

potreba_u_zahotovkah1(M, V):-
    write(M + V),
    nl,
    technology(F, _, M),
    material(M, F, C),
    Z is V * C,
    write(F - Z),
    nl.

func3([A, B], C):-
    write("InF3"),
    nl,
    potreba_u_zahotovkah1(A, C),
    func3(B, C).

func2([A, B], C):-
    write("InF2"),
    nl,
    findall(M, equipment(M, A, _, _), ML),
    write(ML),
    nl,
    func3(ML, C),
    func2(B, C).

potreba_u_zahotovkah(C, G):-
    findall(X, specialization(X, C), XL),
    write(XL),
    nl,
    plan_vypusku(G, S),
    func2(XL, S).
```

Result:

```
?- potreba_u_zahotovkah(wood,table).
[saw,plane]
InF2
[table]
false.
```

Help PLS!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) for a more systematic way to debug your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're up to, but I have an explanation of the unexpected failure you observed.

The query you made wrote the following lines by side-effect (`write/1` and `nl/0`) and then failed:

```
?- potreba_u_zahotovkah(wood,table).
[saw,plane]
InF2
[table]
false.
```

The highlighted line was output by the following highlighted `write/1` and `nl/0`:

```
func2([A, B], C):-
    write("InF2"),
    nl,
    findall(M, equipment(M, A, _, _), ML),
    write(ML),
    nl,
    func3(ML, C),
    func2(B, C).
```

So above variable `ML` was bound to **`[table]`** when the goal `func3(ML, C)` was called.

Looking at your definition of `func3/2` the reason for failure becomes apparent:

```
func3([A, B], C):-
    write("InF3"),
    nl,
    potreba_u_zahotovkah1(A, C),
    func3(B, C).
```

The clause head of `func3/2` demands that the first argument is a list having exactly two elements. The list `[table]`, however, has exactly **one** element, not two!

As no more choicepoint are open, the goal `potreba_u_zahotovkah(wood,table)` fails.