# Is there a command to show the search pointer of every step in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand the **exact search order** of Prolog. In my university course script there are shown **traces** that show exactly where the "pointer" is at the moment. Let the following be our database:

```
a(a, a, b).
a(a, a, c).
a(a, a, d).
a(a, a, e).
a(a, a, f).
```

Then the **output** of Prolog should be something like this:

```
?- a(a, a, f).
   a(a, a, b).     fail
   a(a, a, c).     fail
   a(a, a, d).     fail
   a(a, a, e).     fail
   a(a, a, f).     succ
```

Here I can see exactly where prolog is searching right now and whether the unification is possible or not. This view would be very helpful when trying to understand **rules and recursion** in Prolog.

I have tried to use **trace/0**, **trace/1** and **debug/0**. But it just shows me rather confusing and IMO unnecessary information.

**Is there a command in Prolog to view something like I mentioned above?** Thanks!

Comment: Do you watch the exact trajectory of each and every molecule in your famous flask? No, you don't. For similar reasons it is not too helpful to watch each and every of Prolog's tiny moves. Instead, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) for better ways.

Comment: @false Thanks for your answer. Your link is quite confusing to me, because I have just begun learning prolog and I have no idea of exceptions. Comming from imperative programming I know the order of execution all the time. I want to know the sme for prolog programs (at least when they are small).

Comment: Please look at the linked examples there! (Yes, for the moment you can skip exceptions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  [user] .

  a(a, a, b).
  a(a, a, c).
  a(a, a, d).
  a(a, a, e).
  a(a, a, f).

  end_of_file .
```

_

```
  ?- leash(-all) .
  true.

  ?- spy(a) .
  true.
```

_

```
  ?- a(P,Q,R) , false ; true .

   * Call: (11) a(_4702, _4704, _4706)
   * Exit: (11) a(a, a, b)
   * Exit: (11) a(a, a, c)
   * Exit: (11) a(a, a, d)
   * Exit: (11) a(a, a, e)
   * Exit: (11) a(a, a, f)
  true.
```