# A "display" that always displays in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `check(Data,Res)` that checks`Dats` according to some rules and returns `Res` (a function result on `Data`, assuming `Data` answers to several criteria).

I have another function `generate(N,Data)` which generates a `N`-size `Data`.

My main program begins with generating many `1`-size `Data`, then if none answered the criteria, we go on to `2`-size `Data` and so on until we reach a certain `M` upper limit.

```
main(M):- next_number(N,M), generate(N,Data), check(Data,Res).
```

However, the program runs for very long time. I wanted to make sure it does not get stuck. For this, I wanted to print the generated `Data` each time before its being checked. But adding `display` did not assist, because it only actually displayed if the entire statement was true.

That's not what I want.

I want to keep track of the progran using `display`, similarly to `System.out.println` in Java.

Is there any other function that displays anyway? Or an idea how to use `display` in a way that will always display, regardless if the `Data` answered the criteria or not?

I thought to do:

```
(check(Data,Res) -> display(Data);display(Data)).
```

But I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your long process is likely to be within check - or more precisely, that check fails for most data, causing the system to backtrack repeatedly.
If you display a result in check, you'll have line upon line of tracing. Instead, you could add a write statement to generate, or even to your number generation:

```
main(M):-
    next_number_and_tick(N,M),
    generate(N,Data),
    check(Data,Res).

next_number_and_tick(N,M) :-
    next_number(N,M),
    write('Tick - now doing '),
    writeln(N).
```

Upon backtracking, the program will signal the data size it is now working on, giving you an idea of the volume of work it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the way you *use* display is that the entire statement must be *true* for it to display. Your idea of using "if-then" is good but not accurate. If you want to use it, you should "trick" prolog the following way:

```
new_check(Data,Res) :- (check(Data,Res) -> display('Victory!'),!; display('Failed Data: '), display(Data), nl, fail).
```

This way, if the check fails, you will get a report on which `Data` failed, and if it succeeded everything stops (assuming you want only 1 solution. If you want more, remoce the `!` predicate).