# CLPFD and recursive formulations

Tags: prolog, shortest-path, clpfd, north-east-lattice-path

Given a `field`, find the "cheapest" path from `(0, 0)` to `(3, 3)`. Only the moves *up* and *to the right* are allowed.

```
field([
   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   [3, 3, 4, 3],
   [3, 3, 1, 3],
   [3, 3, 1, 1] 
]).

nth([A|_], 0, A).
nth([_|T], I, A) :- I #> 0, J #= I - 1, nth(T, J, A).

at(I, J, E) :- field(M), nth(M, I, R), nth(R, J, E).
```

Here's my recursive solution:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

price(0, 0, P) :- at(0, 0, P).
price(I, 0, P) :-
  I #=< 3,
  I #> 0,
  I0 #= I - 1,
  price(I0, 0, P0),
  at(I, 0, P1),
  P #= P0 + P1.
price(0, J, P) :-
  J #=< 3,
  J #> 0,
  J0 #= J - 1,
  price(0, J0, P0),
  at(0, J, P1),
  P #= P0 + P1.
price(I, J, P) :-
  I #=< 3,
  J #=< 3,
  I #> 0,
  J #> 0,
  I0 #= I - 1,
  J0 #= J - 1,
  price(I0, J, P0),
  price(I, J0, P1),
  at(I, J, P2),
  P #= min(P0, P1) + P2.
```

I can run it in different directions:

```
?- price(3, 3, P).
?- price(I, J, P), I #= 3, J #= 3.
?- price(I, J, P), P #> 10.
```

1. Is it possible to memorize the intermediate steps, and is it strictly necessary?
2. Is there a way to use memorization only when `I` and `J` are grounded?
3. How does CLPFD deal with the fact that there are 4 rules for the predicate `price`? Does the library merge the different rules into one big if?
4. Is it better to write a single rule `price` with `if_`'s inside?

Comment: @GuyCoder: Compared to other questions here, OP is pretty focused showing even *working* programs for what has been done so far.

Comment: With enough time and experience, one can certainly induce the high-level behaviour of CLP solutions and how they interact with the rest of Prolog. If you think this is subjective "handwavy" stuff, and the only ground truth about CLP + Prolog is execution trace, then you indirectly answered my questions, although I must note that one of the primary attractions of Prolog is that this is one of the very few languages where one can reason about statements without resorting to procedural interpretation.

Comment: @GuyCoder: I also must add that this solution was written completely without any tracing or debugging, and worked pretty much immediately after I fixed syntactic issues and added `#=< 3` constraints. I only cared about the logical soundness of the predicates. Hope this clarifies where my question originates from.

Comment: @vasily: *the only ground truth about CLP + Prolog is execution trace* oh please no! There are [many alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791637/772868) most notably generalizations and specializations.

Comment: your code actually moves down and to the right, not that it matters. :)

Comment: @GuyCoder I think the tag should be named "north-east-lattice-path". since it contains only one question (this), all it takes is to make a tag edit on this Q. but I don't think the info/tag wiki will go along automatically, so it will have to be copied manually. if you agree with the change, would you do the change, so your name stays on the new tag wiki edit history (since you were the original creator of this tag)?

Comment: @WillNess I thought the same right after pressing Enter when entering the name. I noted that `north-east-lattice` is now deprecated and to use `north-east-lattice-path`. I also didn't change it immediately to see if anyone really notice or cared. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 2):

Ad 3, current implementations of `clpfd/clpz` are all a library that has very few connections to the actual compilation process ("preparation for execution"). So there is no such predicate-wise optimization that you are hoping for. The clauses remain and are tried out one after the other — maybe with a little bit indexing due to the 0es  in the head.  If you want to get efficient code, you need to combine the common cases directly. E.g., you might first consider in a single rule `I in 1..3, J in 1..3` and then avoid all those other comparisons.  This means you would need some intermediary auxiliary predicate.

Also note the fine difference between `I #=< 3, I #> 0` and `I in 1..3`. The former succeeds for `I = 1+0` while the latter produces a type error. And for `0+0` OTOH, your program fails. You probably want at least consistent behaviour wherefore you may also use `(#)/1` in places where general expressions are expected.

Ad 4, `if_/3` or rather `reif` might be of interest, because you have just the special case of 0. Also, please note that often in stead of nesting `if_/3` you may use a more complex reified condition as [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590) on page 8 in `treememberd_t/3`.

Ad 1&2 there is some support for this in some systems, but it still is very bleeding edge. In particular if you want to use it together with constraints.

---

One final remark about your code in general. What you did was to take one-by-one an existing algorithm and you recoded it directly. Think of the last clause where you explore two paths independently and then join their results.  You only can do this, because you know a lot about the actual problem, in particular both paths will have a solution.  The only case were actual non-determinism happens is the instantiation of the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

As I show in my other answer here your recursive solution behaves exponentially. The usual approach to counter this is to add memoization. But memoized recursion's results are straightforwardly achieved, by flipping the time arrow, with a *dynamic programming* approach which just creates the field of resulting optimal prices from the given field right away; that field of prices can then be freely queried using `nth` or its built-in equivalents.

In the following I will assume `field` is a fully present NxN list structure. The elements of these lists might or might not be instantiated.

```
% field(Field), prices(Field,Prices).
prices([],[]).
prices([R1|Rs],[Q1|Qs]):-
   a(R1,0,Q1),  
   bs(Rs,Q1,Qs). 

a([],_,[]).
a([A|AT],P0,[P|PT]):- P #= P0+A, a(AT,P,PT).

bs([],_,[]).
bs([R|Rs],[P0|Q0],[Q|Qs]):- b(R,P0,[P0|Q0],Q), bs(Rs,Q,Qs).

b([],_,[],[]).
b([A|AT],P01,[P0|PT0],[P|PT]):- P #= min(P0,P01)+A, b(AT,P,PT0,PT).
```

Testing:

```
69 ?- time(( field(_F),maplist(writeln,_F),writeln('----'),
             prices(_F,_X),maplist(writeln,_X) )).
[1,1,1,1,1,1]
[3,3,4,3,2,5]
[3,3,1,3,1,3]
[3,3,1,1,4,3]
[3,3,1,1,4,2]
[3,3,7,1,4,1]
----
[1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[4,  5, 7, 7, 7,11]
[7,  8, 8,10, 8,11]   % (hand formatted)
[10,11, 9,10,12,14]
[13,14,10,11,15,16]
[16,17,17,12,16,17]
% 289 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.027 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.
```

This doesn't *literally* answer any of your four questions, but it shows how the memoized recursion can be coded with a dynamic programming approach.

Comment: the downside is that the field is fully explored and the resulting prices are fully created, instead of being driven by I,J which might be much less than N. this surely can be addressed with some modification to the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

To the last half of your question 1, of course memoization is worth it here, your code [clocks as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) exponential instead of quadratic (which obviates your 2, I think):

```
30 ?- time( (I=5, J=5, price(I, J, P)) ).
% 19,120 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.007 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
I = J, J = 5,
P = 17 ;
% 10,163 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.002 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.

31 ?- time( (I=4, J=4, price(I, J, P)) ).
% 5,120 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.003 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
I = J, J = 4,
P = 15 ;
% 2,771 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.

32 ?- time( (I=3, J=3, price(I, J, P)) ).
% 1,366 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
I = J, J = 3,
P = 10 ;
% 769 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.

33 ?- _X = [ 19.12/5.12, 5.12/1.37 ], maplist(is,A,_X).
A = [3.734375, 3.7372262773722627].

34 ?- _X = [ 29.3/7.9, 7.9/2.15 ], maplist(is,A,_X).
A = [3.7088607594936707, 3.674418604651163].
```

I ran the above with your code which I modified to enlarge the field, as follows:

```
field([
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5],
   [3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3],
   [3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3],
   [3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2],
   [3, 3, 7, 1, 4, 1]
]).

price(0, 0, P) :- at(0, 0, P).
price(I, 0, P) :-
  I #=< 5,
  .... .
price(0, J, P) :-
  J #=< 5,
  .... .
price(I, J, P) :-
  I #=< 5,
  J #=< 5,
  .... .
```