# Prolog add N to 0 to the list

Tags: list, prolog, addition

I want to add to Result list N to 0 digits.

The sample query

```
?- add(5,R).
```

should return the answer:

```
R = [5,4,3,2,1,0].
```

I already tried the following code but it did not work.

```
add(0, 0).
add(N, [R]) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   add(N1, [R|N]).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close!

```
add(0, [0]).
add(N, [N|R]) :- 
  N > 0, 
  N1 is N-1, 
  add(N1, R).
```

So, what's different here?

1. `add(0, [0])` has `[0]` instead of `0` because you're building a list, not an integer; otherwise you get the rather awkward looking `[5,4,3,2,1|0]` result.
2. `N > 0` as a guard, to ensure that we don't loop crawling through negative numbers forever once we hit the base case.
3. The work is being done in the head of the second clause of `add/2` instead of the body of it. To wit, our pattern is `add(N, [N|R])` instead of `add(N, [R])`. This is because this term adds N to the head of the list rather than adding it before recurring.
4. Similarly, you have a simple inversion in `[R|N]`; this would build lists kind of backwards.

All in all, I think you were very close. A little more experimenting at the prompt may have been sufficient to fix it. Have you tried using `trace/0` yet?

Comment: First, thank you about your explanation. I learnd it very well. I did not know about tracing. I searched it for a while. It is very useful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

We show an analog of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32651292/4609915) (which dealed with consecutive integers *ascending* from `0`).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
```

Based on [`equidistant_stride/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32651292/4609915) we query:

```
?- N = 10, Zs = [N|_Zs0], length(_Zs0, N), equidistant_stride(Zs, -1).
N = 10, Zs = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0].
```

Let's re-run<sup>1</sup> the runtime measurements we did in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33926257/4609915)!

```
?- between(1,6,E),
   N is 10^E,
   garbage_collect,
   call_time(numlist(0, N, _), T1_in_ms),
   garbage_collect,
   call_time((_Zs = [N|_Z], length(_Z, N), equidistant_stride(_Zs, -1)), T2_in_ms).
  N =      10, T1_in_ms =  0, T2_in_ms =   0
; N =     100, T1_in_ms =  1, T2_in_ms =   0
; N =    1000, T1_in_ms =  1, T2_in_ms =   1
; N =   10000, T1_in_ms =  3, T2_in_ms =  12
; N =  100000, T1_in_ms = 14, T2_in_ms =  32
; N = 1000000, T1_in_ms = 90, T2_in_ms = 280.
```

---

**Edit**

Past revisions of this answer inadvertently sk(r)ewed runtime measurements in favor of [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd). How? 
It's simple: A `reverse/2` goal followed `numlist/3`, even though it is useless in this setting.

This should be better now: Thx 2 @JanWielemaker 4 reporting!

---

<sub>**Footnote 1:** Using SWI-Prolog version 7.3.11 (64-bit).</sub>

Comment: @JanWielemaker. Better now! Isn't it nice to see these little binary predicates cooperate like this?

Comment: Yes and no.  Your cheating a little by adding `reverse/2`.  It is just as easy to write a numlist/3 that gets the order right.  That is why I omitted the reverse for the timing comparison.  What remains is the comparison between an obvious **algorithm** and a declarative specification for which we merely have to hope that the constraint solver is clever enough to find the right algorithm.  Given a complex search problem, it is wise to try constraints first.  A good **algorithm** however is **predictable**.

Comment: @JanWielemaker. True, a little:)  I did not intend to rig the comparison. Will edit to improve fairness.

Comment: @JanWielemaker. Regarding the predictability of algorithm performance I'm sceptical: (1) In general, yes, (2) but, (3) with varying accuracy, (4) better for abstract measures than for measured runtime, because (5) actual CPUs do a mirage of stunts like caches, predictors, speculative execution, paged virtual memory to raise the average case performance of legacy code.

Comment: @JanWielemaker. How about SWI supporting huge-pages? TLB is a precious resource, after all. And how about SIMD-izing the GC (say for marking)? Now that the low hanging fruit got picked, vector gather/scatter has reached mainstream CPUs. It's time we use it! 4 U c, I got lots of splendid ideas:)

Answer (score 1):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
```

We define `n_to_0/2` like this:

```
n_to_0(N,[Z|Zs]) :-
   length(Zs,N),
   [Z|Zs] ins 0..N,
   chain([Z|Zs],#>).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
?- n_to_0(5,Zs).
Zs = [5,4,3,2,1,0].
```

How about the most general query using `n_to_0/2`?

```
?- n_to_0(N,Zs).
  N = 0, Zs =             [0]
; N = 1, Zs =           [1,0]
; N = 2, Zs =         [2,1,0]
; N = 3, Zs =       [3,2,1,0]
; N = 4, Zs =     [4,3,2,1,0]
; N = 5, Zs =   [5,4,3,2,1,0]
; N = 6, Zs = [6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
...
```

---

**Edit**

@JanWielemaker pointed out that `n_to_0/2` (as defined above) is *abysmally* slow—particularly when comparing it to its non-clpfd counterpart:
Thanks a lot for reporting! 
See for yourself...

```
?- between(1, 3, E),
   N is 10^E, 
   call_time((numlist(0, N, _Zs0), reverse(_Zs0, _)), T1_in_ms),
   call_time(n_to_0(N, _), T2_in_ms).
  E = 1, N =   10, T1_in_ms = 0, T2_in_ms =     1
; E = 2, N =  100, T1_in_ms = 0, T2_in_ms =   104
; E = 3, N = 1000, T1_in_ms = 0, T2_in_ms = 29701
...
```

Check out [this new, improved, clpfd-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952999/4609915)!

Comment: Yes, this can work too but out teacher does not want us to use libraries.

Comment: It is surely nicely declarative.  It also uses specialized constraints, which makes it more a _library_ solution.  And, it is really **slow**.   Just visit http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/pjAHBXed.pl

Comment: Regarding the wording "library solution": It is in my view limiting and detrimental to provide a Prolog system where integer constraints are not at least autoloaded. Almost all Prolog snippets on Stackoverflow would or already *do* benefit from declarative integer arithmetic. I wish SWI would act like GNU Prolog and B-Prolog, and just make CLP(FD) constraints available out of the box. There is no conflict with other library predicates anyways, now that SWI finally, like SICStus, has `transpose_ugraph/2`, 8 years after the `transpose/2` conflict was first reported and long solved in SICStus.

Comment: @mat. I second your opinion. Of course! Do you remember your first Prolog query? Your first Prolog query *ever*? I do and I guess you do, too: `?- stadt(X).` (Note "Stadt" is German for "town" / "city"). Other suitable "first" queries include IMO `?- 1+1 #= 2.` and `?- X #> 1, X #< 4.` and `?- X #\= 0.` and many more... but definitely not `?-  use_module(library(clpfd)).`.