# Creating [1,2,3...,N] list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'd like to create a predicate `arrayLEQ(L,N)` that is true when `L = [1,2,3,...,N]`.

I tried to do it recursively:

```
arrayLEQ(L,N) :- arrayLEQ([],L,1,N).
arrayLEQ(L1,L2,N,N) :- append(L1,[N],L2).
arrayLEQ(L1,L2,F,N) :- Fnext is F+1, append(L1,[F],L1n), arrayLEQ(L1n,L2,Fnext,N).
```

At first I thought that it will work, but sadly it doesn't.

When I do:
`?- arrayLEQ(L,5)` I get `L = [1,2,3,4,5]` which is the right answer, but Prolog is ready to look for another answer, which is not wanted.

Would you mind explaining to me what I did wrong and why Prolog tries to look for another answer to this predicate, even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at the *very* similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611228/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-ascending-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at tracer after the first query succeed:

```
?- arrayLEQ(L,5).
L = [1,2,3,4,5].
more

 Redo:arrayLEQ([1, 2, 3, 4], _5040, 5, 5)
 Call:_5844 is 5+1
 Exit:6 is 5+1
 Call:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4], [5], _5854)
 Exit:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 Call:...
 Call:_5880 is 6+1
 Exit:7 is 6+1
 Call:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6], _5890)
 Exit:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
 Call:arrayLEQ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], _5040, 7, 5)
 Call:_5922 is 7+1
 Exit:8 is 7+1
 Call:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7], _5932)
 Exit:lists:append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
 Call:arrayLEQ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], _5040, 8, 5)
 Call:_5970 is 8+1
 Exit:9 is 8+1
 and so on...
```

You can see that your program keeps adding element into the list, without stopping. So there are two solutions:

- Adding a cut (`!`): `arrayLEQ(L1,L2,N,N):- !, append(L1,[N],L2).` It works but maybe (in my opinion) there is a better solution.
- When adding an element, you don't check if you have already passed the threshod you set (in this case `5`). So you just have to add `F < N` before doing `Fnext is F+1`. So: `arrayLEQ(L1,L2,F,N) :- F < N, Fnext is F+1, append(L1,[F],L1n), arrayLEQ(L1n,L2,Fnext,N)`. (personally i prefer this solution)

So the query now (with second solution):

```
?- arrayLEQ(L,5).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
more.
false.
```

I suggest you to not use `append/3` because in this case is not necessary at all and write someting like this:

```
orderedList(L,N):-
    orderedList(L,1,N).
orderedList([N],N,N). %you can add a cut ! here, to avoid further search
orderedList([H|T],C,N):-
    C < N,
    H is C,
    C1 is C+1,
    orderedList(T,C1,N).

?- orderedList(L,5).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
more
false
```

Then if you need to return an empty list, wou can add a predicate to handle this case easily... BTW check also the question linked in the comments by @repeat

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! I quite new to Prolog and it helped me alot !